# Spam values in database even after adding form validations and google recaptcha

Tags: php, mysql, forms, recaptcha, spam

we have a PHP form and MySQL database with it. We also have validations on our form which work perfectly. We have also added Google ReCaptcha on our form.
But the issue is that we still get spam values in our database.
All the fields in the form are required fields and still there are null values in spam rows in the database.

How is that possible and how do I stop spam entries in the database.

Comment: use back-end validation , in your code.

Comment: Share your code and table structure, and we'll be able to give a more precise answer. But you should always, always validate input server-side too

Comment: if verification is only done on the client side, and a specific url used as a target for the form, spam bots can submit data directly to the url. Means validating server-side. One trick often used is to put a hidden text input in the form that have to stay empty. Span bots will often try to fill this value, and you can cancel the submission if this field has a value.

Comment: `!empty($_POST['name'])` for null values.

Comment: `if($_POST['name'] == NULL || $_POST['name'] == ""` try validations like this one or yeah the `empty()` functions does the work too however note that `0` is an exception to `empty` function

Comment: @Kaddath nice solution (Y)

Comment: I have an empty hiddin field on my form too..... Please help me on how to do server-side validation. Thank you.